# How to solve the issue "Testing accuracy reduce during iterations"?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

I am designing a new network architecture for semantic segmentation. The training loss reduces when training iteration increases. However, when I measure the testing accuracy. I got the below figure

> From 0 to 20.000 iterations, the accuracy increase. However, after 20.000 iterations, the testing accuracy reduce. I guess it is overfitting issue.

I tried to add dropout to the network, but the graph trend is similar. Could you suggest to me the reason and how can I solve it? I  think early stopping is not good solution. Thanks

[image]

Comment: Overfitting (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting)? You can try to add more data or try to simplify model

Comment: Actually, in testing, I have fixed data. I cannot have more data because it requires the ground-truth. What does it mean a simplify model?

Comment: @user9264 You still can try to augment your training data (add noise/distortions to existing samples and use same labels). Simplify model - reduce number of layers/filters, for example

Comment: Also, sometimes is good idea to add L2 regularization for your fully connected layers (but it's maybe not your case). Another approach - stop by validation, you can divide your training data into train/validation sets. Validation set is some kind of testing set. You can track error on validation set and stop learning when this error goes up

Comment: Yes, thanks. I have 500 training data. I divided it into training data (400 image) and validation (100 images). The above graph is validation graph. Not testing. Sorry

Comment: I'm not an expert in ML but 400 examples seems quite small. Maybe augmentation still good idea. You can try to use something like these to increase count of training images https://github.com/aleju/imgaug

Comment: What are your topology characteristics?  Layers, complexity (parameters & weights), classes, batch size, etc. are important in diagnosing over-fitting.  Epoch count is more important than iteration count.  If you're training a model at all comparable to the ILSVRC competition entries with more than a few classes, then 400 training images is not enough data; you'll get over-fitting almost by definition.

Comment: Thanks. I tried another dataset which has 20.000 images for training and 4000 images for validation. I chose the batch size is 4, with a number of class is 10.my network is resnet base, with the parameter is 2 Million. the dropout prob. is 0.2. But the result is similar

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to randomize your data on your training, also you can start testing with a higher learning rate (say 0.1) to get out of local minima then decrease it to a very small value to let settle down things. To do this change the step size to say 1000 iterations to reduce the size of the learning rate every 1000 iterations.